# When using typesafe heterogeneous containers in Java (Bloch #29) is there a way to iterate through the keys of the Map while knowing the generic type?

Tags: java, generics

For example, I can iterate through the keys like this:

```
for (Class<?> key : map.keySet()) {
}
```

but is there a way to get the exact generic type of Class during each iteration?

```
ex. Class<Integer>,Class<String>,etc.
```

Comment: This is not how Generic works. You can get the class of an instance with the keyword `instanceof` or `o.getClass()`. It has nothing to do with the Generics.

Answer (score 1):

When you compile your code to *byte code*, you loose all information about generic type. It is always Object.

To get class type at runtime, you could use `instance of` for each element in collection. As alternative, if you are sure that all elements have the same type, you can check with `instance of` only the first element.

**P.S.** I think about another way, but I did not use it before (`instance of` for me was enough). You can use custom annotation for collection variable in the class.

Comment: So in the above example where I'm iterating over Class<?> keys...I notice that I can get the type (ex. java.lang.String) by calling key.getName().  Is there no way to translate that name to the appropriate class (Class<String>) so that I can pass that into the Map and retrieve the value?  It sounds like there's not, it just surprises me a bit.

Comment: Your exemple makes no sense. You will never iterate over a List of Classes. You do iterate over Objects (undefined instances) : `for (Object obj : srcList) { if(obj instanceof String) String str = (String) obj; }`

Answer (score 0):

It's very unclear what you're asking, and what you mean by "get". You already have the `Class` object at runtime -- it is the value of the variable `key`. Hardcoding specifically-parameterized types at compile time like `Class<Integer>` doesn't make any sense because you are iterating over many different types of classes.